# Get previous non-NaN value of a column in a pandas dataframe to calculate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pd df time series where I have the close price, a filter to determine when to open (1) or close (-1) a position, the size of the position, and the total (size*close):

```
Date        Close   Filter  O_Size  O_Tot
1/5/2018    15.85   1       74      1172.9
1/8/2018    16.50   0       
... 
2/14/2018   16.49   0       
2/15/2018   16.03   -1      
...
```

When the value of Filter is -1, I want to create a new column C_Tot = Close * O_Size, taking the previous  value of size when it is not NaN.

```
Date        Close   Filter  O_Size  O_Tot    C_Tot
1/5/2018    15.85   1       74      1172.9
1/8/2018    16.50   0       
... 
2/14/2018   16.49   0       
2/15/2018   16.03   -1                        1186.22
...
```

I am wondering if I can do that without a loop.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this using limited data you have given here.make all empty cells to nan before using this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

v=[["1/5/2018",15.85 ,  1,       74 ,     1172.9],
["1/8/2018",16.50 ,0       ,np.nan,np.nan],
["2/14/2018" , 16.49,   0  ,np.nan,np.nan]     ,
["2/15/2018",   16.03,   -1      ,np.nan,np.nan]]

df=pd.DataFrame(v,columns=["Date","Close","Filter","O_Size","O_Tot"])

tmp = df[df.Filter==-1]

def func(x):
    spl = df.iloc[:x.name,:]
    val = spl.iloc[spl["O_Size"].last_valid_index()].O_Size*x.Close
    return val

tmp["C_Tot"] = tmp.apply(func,axis=1)
res = pd.concat([df,tmp["C_Tot"]],axis=1)
```

output

```
        Date  Close  Filter  O_Size   O_Tot    C_Tot
0   1/5/2018  15.85       1    74.0  1172.9      NaN
1   1/8/2018  16.50       0     NaN     NaN      NaN
2  2/14/2018  16.49       0     NaN     NaN      NaN
3  2/15/2018  16.03      -1     NaN     NaN  1186.22
```